# cannot read response.json() when sent as part of an object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, http-post

I am making an API call from a function and `return response.json()`, on the calling function I can get the data. But along with response.json() I also need to pass `header` data to the calling function so I created an object and added response.json() and header data to it.

In the calling function I can read `header` data but not the `response.json()`. can you suggest on how to read response data correctly please.

API call function

```
export function loginlibAPI ( id, password ){
    var loginURL = 'https://example.com/sessions';
    return fetch(loginURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "user": {
                'email': id,
                'password': password
            }            
        }),
    })
    .then((response) =>{
          consoleLog('loginUser_lib - header ' + response.headers.get('Authorization-X'));  

    if (response.headers.get('content-type').match(/application\/json/)) {
        consoleLog('inside content type');        
        //return response.json(); // works 
        return { response: response.json(), authorizationToken: response.headers.get('Authorization-X') }; //can not read the response in the calling function
    }
    return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        consoleLog('Error from loginlibAPI() api call - ' + error.message);
    });
}
```

calling function

```
loginUser_lib = async (  ) => {
    const returned = await loginlibAPI( this.state.nationalId, this.state.password ).then((res) => {
      //consoleLog('loginUser_lib - '  + JSON.stringify(res)); // can read data when only response.json() is sent
      consoleLog('loginUser_lib - ' + res.authorizationToken); //works fine - received 'abcdfdlkjsdlkjsdlkj'
      consoleLog('loginUser_lib - ' + res.response);  //returns - [object Object]
      consoleLog('loginUser_lib - ' + JSON.stringify(res.response)); //returns - {"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `response.json()` returns a **promise**, so you'd need to resolve it before you get the data from it. Something like:

```
return response
    .json()
    .then(data => ({
        response: data,
        authorizationToken: response.headers.get('Authorization-X')
    });
```